# Check if a GeoPosition is within a city in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

i am working with GPS Tracks of cars and i would like to find out whether a certain gps point (given in lat/lon) is within a city (and its boundaries/suburbs/etc.) or if it is on the "countryside".
With "countryside" i mean everything that is not defined as "city". Therefore i consider towns, villages, etc. as "countryside".
Basically i want to filter out city-traffic from my data.

Is there a simple way to query this via OpenStreetMaps?

I've already tried to find some tags or attributes on OSM that would indicate whether a gps point is within a city or not. The only relevant attribute i found would be in the "Enclosing Features" tag:
If some point is NOT within a city (and therefore on the countryside) there always seems to be a tag called "City Boundary".
This tag does not exist if the point is within a city.

Example:
Some point (in Berlin) that I would classify as "City":
http://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=52.4662&lon=13.4824

Some point (outside of Berlin) that I would classify as "Countryside":
http://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=52.3362&lon=13.9618

Comment: I think you need to refine what you mean by "city", both in selection (what is a city? a settlement with a certain number of inhabitants? a continuous residential area of some minimum size?) and delimitation (do you want administrative boundaries of the city? maximum distance from built-up areas?)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In the end, for my purposes it was enough to simply create a list of cities (that were of interest for my project) and for each specified a bounding circle with a certain radius. If a GPS point lies within one of the specified bounding circles, i consider it as "within a city".

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution, but enough for my purposes:

- I simply created a list of cities (that were of interest for my project)
- for each city, I specified a "bounding circle" with a certain radius (for instance 50km)
- If a GPS point lies within one of the specified bounding circles, i consider it as "within a city"

Another similar simple solution I figured out:

1. Create a list of all cities, towns, villages, etc. (that are of your interest) with their ZIP-Code and its population
2. Using all cities, villages, etc. of Austria for example, there exist some [tables](https://www.statistik.at/web_de/klassifikationen/regionale_gliederungen/gemeinden/index.html) that have its ZIP-Code and population.
3. In Austria a city is given when the population is > 10.000 (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_St%C3%A4dte_in_%C3%96sterreich)
4. For all GPS locations, query OSM and receive their [postal-codes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:postal_code)
5. Then simply check the GPS location's postal code in your list. If the population is >10.000 its "within a city".